# React: Mapping array inside object

Tags: reactjs

I'm struggling with something that *should* be so simple. I have an Object called `entry` that contains Arrays:

```
  "timestamp": "Sun Jul 12 2020 23:36:26 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)",
  "location": "İstanbul, Turkey",
  "think": [
    "Albanian",
    "Slovenian"
  ],
  "dream": "Turkish",
  "geolocation": [
    41.0082376,
    28.9783589
  ]
}
```

and I want to map over the **think** array. No matter what I try returns the error:
`TypeError: entry.think is undefined`.

I was sure this would work but it isn't:

```
{entry.think.map((think, index) => (
  <p key={index}>{think}</p>
))}
```

**EDIT:**

The entire component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import firebase from "../firebase";

import "../services/localizationService";


const EntrySingle = ({ match }) => {
  const { params: { singleId } } = match;
  const [entry, setEntry] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("entries")
      .doc('' + singleId)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        const data = doc.data();
        setEntry(data);
      });
  }, [singleId]);

  console.log(entry);

  return (
    <>
      <p>dream: {entry.dream}</p>
      <p>think: {entry.think}</p>
      {entry.think.map((think, index) => {
        return <p key={index}>{think}</p>
      })}
      <p>location: {entry.location}</p>
      <p>geolocation: {entry.geolocation}</p>
    </>
  );
};

export default EntrySingle;
```

When I return `<p>think: {entry.think}</p>` it *does* show the contents in html like this:

`think: AlbanianSlovenian`

Comment: What is the error? Also is it possible to provide a full example? Perhaps where you are executing that code?

Comment: You need to tell what the error message says.

Comment: `TypeError: entry.think is undefined`

Comment: Well then the object isn't what you think it is. What does `console.log(entry)` output (and is it an object)?

Comment: @Jamesco could you please update your question and provide full object response, I guess something missing over there and also please update error as well in the question body.

Comment: console.log(entry) is the first code block I put in the message. The console is telling me it's an Object, and `think` is an array inside it

Comment: Sorry, but without a [mcve] it's impossible to guess what the problem might be. If you have a variable called `entry` and it's an object with an array in key `think`, then `entry.think` can't throw an error, so the problem is somewhere else. Showing the entire component would be a good start.

Comment: Based on the scarce information you provided I can only assume - could it be that you are fetching this object from an API and you call `map()` on it before it has finished fetching?

Comment: Bingo – `entry` is an empty array before the firebase request has finished. Didn't you find it odd that the error message is shown *before* the output from the `console.log(entry)` line?

Comment: Change the initial value to `const [entry, setEntry] = useState(null);` and add `if(!entry) { return <div>Loading...</div>; }` before the actual content. Doesn't make sense to initialize to an empty array if the data is expected to be an object.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what might work:

```
const EntrySingle = ({ match }) => {
  const {
    params: { singleId },
  } = match;
  const [entry, setEntry] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("entries")
      .doc("" + singleId)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        const data = doc.data();
        setEntry(data);
      });
  }, [singleId]);

  console.log(entry);

  return (
    <>
      <p>dream: {entry.dream}</p>
      <p>think: {entry.think}</p>
      {entry &&
        entry.think &&
        entry.think.length &&
        entry.think.map((think, index) => {
          return <p key={index}>{think}</p>;
        })}
      <p>location: {entry.location}</p>
      <p>geolocation: {entry.geolocation}</p>
    </>
  );
};
```

Basically you were trying to access `entry` before it was fetched from firestore.

Comment: It still returns nothing. I had previously tried something similar and it wasn't displaying.

Comment: Is it returning undefined only for `think`? Also what is `singleId`? When does the `useEffect` fire?

Comment: Firebase returns an object. `entry.length` will never be true.

Comment: that last edit works! adding `entry.think.length` was the missing piece. thanks!